# How can you detect when a click event has been raised by jquery.trigger?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that doing some action while it's clicked. For example

```
$(function() {

    $('button1').click(function(e){
        /** This is just a pseudocode

        if( me.triggering ) {
            doTrigger();
        }else{
            doClick();
        }

        **/
    })

    $('button2').click(function(e){
        $('button1').trigger('click')
    })

});
```

How can you tell whether the event is executing by a call to `trigger` or from a user click?

Comment: yaaa what you want to know ?

Comment: So you want to see if the other button is triggering your event handler? Why don't you just call another function?

Comment: Be more specific regarding your queston.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for `e.originalEvent`. It sould be set in case of real click:

```
$('button1').click(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) {
        doClick();
    }
    else {
        doTrigger();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCzaC/

You can also pass aditional flag parameter when triggering event to distinguish trigger:

```
$('#button1').trigger('click', [true]);

$('#button1').click(function (e, trigger) {
    if (!trigger) {
        alert('do click');
    } else {
        alert('do trigger');
    }
})
```

Comment: That's probably what the OP is asking for, but why would you do this?